# swap filenames when their substring match

Tags: bash, shell

There are 1000+ images in *folder1* with filenames **"Firstname_Lastname_0032somenumber.jpg"**. I have to replace some of those images with 200+ updated images in *folder2* with filenames **"firstname lastname.jpg"**

So I'm trying to work on a bash script to do this, but I couldn't complete

1. store filenames into 2 arrays (arr1, arr2)

   ```
    shopt -s nullglob 
    arr1=(folder1/*)
    arr2=(folder2/*)
   ```
2. get the substring of the filename (firstname/lastname) of each element in the arr1

   ```
   for i in "${arr1[@]}"
    do
      echo "$i" | cut -d'/' -f 2 | cut -d'_' -f 1 |  tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
   done
   ```
3. check the substring whether matches to the substring in the arr2
4. rename the file

Comment: please don't forget to up vote any answers that provide useful information and 'accept' the answer (formally) to indicate which one you used to solve your problem. That's how StackOverflow.com site works to get maximum help to maximum number of people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better solution would be associative arrays. The first step is like your code in step #2 to create an array where the file names from `folder1` are keys:

```
declare -A map
for i in "${arr1[@]}"; do
   key=$(basename "$i" | cut -d'_' -f 1-2 |  tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | tr '_' ' ')
   map[$key]="$i"
done
```

This converts `Firstname_Lastname_0032somenumber.jpg` to `firstname lastname` (all lower case, `_` replaced by space).

Now you loop over the files in folder 2, process them in a similar way to get the key to fetch the new file name:

```
for i in "${arr2[@]}"; do
   key=$(basename "$i" .jpg | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
   newName=${aa[$key]}
   if [[ -n "$newName" ]]; then
       echo "mv \"$folder2/$i\" \"$folder1/$newName\""
   fi
done
```

Related:

- http://www.artificialworlds.net/blog/2012/10/17/bash-associative-array-examples/

Comment: The problem with this approach is it doesn't scale as well because you're caching all the files in a directory (of any size in an age of zetabytes potentially) in memory.

Comment: OP said "1000+" files. But BASH will do that anyway since it has no API to iterate over the entries in a directory (`$folder1/*` expands to a list of all files, so BASH keeps them all in memory). Lastly, most file systems are so slow with huge number of files in a single folder that it usually doesn't matter :-)

Answer (score 0):

My approach might be something more like reading the files in a loop from folder1 one at a time, stripping off the leading part of the path from the file (you can use basename and dirname commands to split off path components), then splitting file name into tokens, recombining the tokens and copying them to folder2 by appending the fixed up file name to that string.

```
for path in $(ls "folder1/"*); do {
  file=$(/usr/bin/basename path)
  firstAndLast=${file%_*}
  first=${firstAndLast%%_*}
  last=${firstAndLast##*_}
  outputPath=folder2/${first}${last}.jpg
}
```

You can also translate the string alphabetic case, of course, similar to what you've done.  You should be able to find basename and dirname in /usr/bin or /bin in a *NIX system.

Comment: `$(folder1/*)` will try to execute the first file in the folder and pass every other file to it as argument. You probably meant `"$folder1/"*`

Comment: @AaronDigulla  actually, I meant `$(ls folder1/*)`, I will correct it in my example

Comment: That works in this case but it's brittle when `folder1` contains files with spaces in their names.

Comment: @AaronDigulla - Good point.  The your first suggestion was probably right and the ls is superfluous.  I'll edit it again.